# PHP registration form: Make the inputs with red borders if there is an error

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a registration form with PHP and I'd like to do something: if user has not completed the form correctly, I want, in addition to the error message, make the inputs (where there is an error) with red borders.

My registration form (HTML part):

```
<?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>

<div class="flash-message error">
    <h3>You have not completed the form correctly. The error(s) come(s) from the following thing(s):</h3>
    <ol>
        <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
        <li>
            <p><?= $error; ?></p>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<h1 class="page-heading"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="nickname">Nickname:</label> <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text">
            <p class="input-description">Your nickname will be as an identity on the site; it will be displayed wherever you will post, etc.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="your@email.com">
            <p class="input-description">Enter a valid email to receive the confirmation link to validate your account.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password">Password:</label> <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
            <p class="input-description">Enter a password to sign in to your account. Try to put a difficult password to make it more complicated to find.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password-confirmation">Password Confirmation:</label> <input id="password-confirmation" name="password-confirmation" type="password">
            <p class="input-description">Confirm the password that you have put in the field above.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" class="button primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Current result: http://prntscr.com/86h5r2

PHP code:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST))
{

    /* Nickname */

    if(empty($_POST["nickname"]))
    {
        $errors["nickname"] = "You have not completed the nickname field.";
    }

    elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]+$/", $_POST["nickname"]))
    {
        $errors["nickname"] = "Your nickname is not valid.";
    }

    /* E-mail */

    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $errors["email"] = "You have not completed the email field.";
    }

    elseif(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $errors["email"] = "Your email is not valid.";
    }

    /* Password */

    if(empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $errors["password"] = "You have not completed the two password fields.";
    }

    elseif($_POST["password"] != $_POST["password-confirmation"])
    {
        $errors["password"] = "The passwords did not match. Please enter the same password in both fields.";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: any code in there for something you tried? I don't see "red" or any CSS code for it. This is CSS 101 stuff.

Comment: I need something like Facebook: http://prntscr.com/86h7uk

Comment: ok... so what is the question; you want us to write the codes for you? This is basic CSS stuff.

Comment: No, I just need the solution to do that. I know that it's not difficult to do, but I don't know how I can do that. I created the code. I just learn PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to add a border to the input with error you would want to embed  a php if statement like this in the class attributes. just define classname in your css

```
<input type="text" class="<?=  isset($error['name']) ? 'has-error'  : ''   ?>" value="" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a style to the `<li>` is one way

```
<ol>
    <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
    <li style="border:red solid 1px">
        <p><?= $error; ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

A better way would be to create some css and then just add a class to your `<li>`

```
<style>
  .an-error-msg {
     border:red solid 1px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
     -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
   }
</style>

<ol>
    <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
    <li class="an-error-msg">
        <p><?= $error; ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I need exactly, is that if the user has an error, there is a red border for the input error. I want something like Facebook made: http://prntscr.com/86h7uk

Comment: Just play with the CSS until you get what you want, added a bit of rounded corners to start you off

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it client side with the `required` attribute like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kn7qjg6c/

**HTML**

```
 <form method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="name" required/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input:required:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```